# Compiled lambda expressions used as property getters and setters: wrong benchmarking method or wrong lambda expression construction?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, properties, benchmarking

Hi I was trying out using (cached) compiled lambda expressions for properties access, for sure I got a result much better (i.e. faster) than when using PropertyInfo.GetValue()/SetValue() method calls. However, I feel it's still really far getting close to the "native" properties speed. Is it the benchmarking method that makes the results so different from what others could get?

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/584720/ExpressionplusbasedplusPropertyplusGettersplusandp
- http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2012/2/4/reflection-vs-compiled-expressions-vs-delegates-performance-comparision
- [Compiled C# Lambda Expressions Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568294/compiled-c-sharp-lambda-expressions-performance)

Here is below the result I got after running my piece of code below:

> ```
> Native: Elapsed = 00:00:00.0995876 (99.5876 ms); Step = 1.992E-005 ms
> Lambda Expression: Elapsed = 00:00:00.5369273 (536.9273 ms); Step = 1.074E-004 ms
> Property Info: Elapsed = 00:00:01.9187312 (1918.7312 ms); Step = 3.837E-004 ms
>
> 1.000 < 5.392 < 19.267
> ```

Honestly I feel that based on others benchmarks, the compiled lambda expressions should be twice slower than using regular properties, not like between 5 - 6 times slower.

Any thought? The bench-marking method? The way the compiled lambda expression is computed?

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var stepCount = 5000000UL;

        var dummy = new Dummy();

        const string propertyName = "Soother";

        const bool propertyValue = true;

        var propertyInfo = typeof(Dummy).GetProperty(propertyName);

        var nativeBenchmark = Benchmark.Run("Native", stepCount, () => dummy.Soother = propertyValue);
        var lambdaExpressionBenchmark = Benchmark.Run("Lambda Expression", stepCount, () => dummy.Set(propertyName, propertyValue));
        var propertyInfoBenchmark = Benchmark.Run("Property Info", stepCount, () => propertyInfo.SetValue(dummy, propertyValue, null));

        var benchmarkReports = new[] { nativeBenchmark, lambdaExpressionBenchmark, propertyInfoBenchmark }.OrderBy(item => item.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        benchmarkReports.Join(Environment.NewLine).WriteLineToConsole();

        var fastest = benchmarkReports.First().ElapsedMilliseconds;

        benchmarkReports.Select(report => (report.ElapsedMilliseconds / fastest).ToString("0.000")).Join(" < ").WriteLineToConsole();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Dummy
{
    public bool? Soother { get; set; } = true;
}

public class BenchMarkReport
{
    #region Fields & Properties

    public string Name { get; }
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime { get; }
    public double ElapsedMilliseconds
    {
        get
        {
            return ElapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
    }
    public ulong StepCount { get; }
    public double StepElapsedMilliseconds
    {
        get
        {
            return ElapsedMilliseconds / StepCount;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    internal BenchMarkReport(string name, TimeSpan elapsedTime, ulong stepCount)
    {
        Name = name;
        ElapsedTime = elapsedTime;
        StepCount = stepCount;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}: Elapsed = {ElapsedTime} ({ElapsedMilliseconds} ms); Step = {StepElapsedMilliseconds:0.###E+000} ms";
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Benchmark
{
    #region Fields & Properties

    private readonly Action _stepAction;

    public string Name { get; }

    public ulong StepCount { get; }

    public Benchmark(string name, ulong stepCount, Action stepAction)
    {
        Name = name;
        StepCount = stepCount;
        _stepAction = stepAction;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public static BenchMarkReport Run(string name, ulong stepCount, Action stepAction)
    {
        var benchmark = new Benchmark(name, stepCount, stepAction);

        var benchmarkReport = benchmark.Run();

        return benchmarkReport;
    }

    public BenchMarkReport Run()
    {
        return Run(StepCount);
    }

    public BenchMarkReport Run(ulong stepCountOverride)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (ulong i = 0; i < StepCount; i++)
        {
            _stepAction();
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        var benchmarkReport = new BenchMarkReport(Name, stopwatch.Elapsed, stepCountOverride);

        return benchmarkReport;
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void WriteToConsole<TInstance>(this TInstance instance)
    {
        Console.Write(instance);
    }

    public static void WriteLineToConsole<TInstance>(this TInstance instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(instance);
    }

    // Goodies: add name inference from property lambda expression
    // e.g. "instance => instance.PropertyName" redirected using "PropertyName"

    public static TProperty Get<TInstance, TProperty>(this TInstance instance, string propertyName)
    {
        return FastPropertyRepository<TInstance, TProperty>.GetGetter(propertyName)(instance);
    }

    public static void Set<TInstance, TProperty>(this TInstance instance, string propertyName, TProperty propertyValue)
    {
        FastPropertyRepository<TInstance, TProperty>.GetSetter(propertyName)(instance, propertyValue);
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static string Join<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, string separator = ", ")
    {
        return string.Join(separator, source);
    }
}

internal static class FastPropertyRepository<TInstance, TProperty>
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, Action<TInstance, TProperty>> Setters;
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, Func<TInstance, TProperty>> Getters;

    static FastPropertyRepository()
    {
        Getters = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Func<TInstance, TProperty>>();
        Setters = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Action<TInstance, TProperty>>();
    }

    public static Func<TInstance, TProperty> GetGetter(string propertyName)
    {
        Func<TInstance, TProperty> getter;
        if (!Getters.TryGetValue(propertyName, out getter))
        {
            getter = FastPropertyFactory.GeneratePropertyGetter<TInstance, TProperty>(propertyName);
            Getters[propertyName] = getter;
        }

        return getter;
    }

    public static Action<TInstance, TProperty> GetSetter(string propertyName)
    {
        Action<TInstance, TProperty> setter;
        if (!Setters.TryGetValue(propertyName, out setter))
        {
            setter = FastPropertyFactory.GeneratePropertySetter<TInstance, TProperty>(propertyName);
            Setters[propertyName] = setter;
        }

        return setter;
    }
}

internal static class FastPropertyFactory
{
    public static Func<TInstance, TProperty> GeneratePropertyGetter<TInstance, TProperty>(string propertyName)
    {
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInstance), "value");

        var propertyValueExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyName);

        var expression = propertyValueExpression.Type == typeof(TProperty) ? propertyValueExpression : (Expression)Expression.Convert(propertyValueExpression, typeof(TProperty));

        var propertyGetter = Expression.Lambda<Func<TInstance, TProperty>>(expression, parameterExpression).Compile();

        return propertyGetter;
    }

    public static Action<TInstance, TProperty> GeneratePropertySetter<TInstance, TProperty>(string propertyName)
    {
        var instanceParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInstance));

        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProperty), propertyName);

        var propertyValueExpression = Expression.Property(instanceParameterExpression, propertyName);

        var conversionExpression = propertyValueExpression.Type == typeof(TProperty) ? parameterExpression : (Expression)Expression.Convert(parameterExpression, propertyValueExpression.Type);

        var propertySetter = Expression.Lambda<Action<TInstance, TProperty>>(Expression.Assign(propertyValueExpression, conversionExpression), instanceParameterExpression, parameterExpression).Compile();

        return propertySetter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run your results using Release? The results might surprise you.

Comment: I also think you might want to simplify the benchmark into individual methods rather than passing the action around. I'm not an expert of the JIT, but I would suspect that would have something to do with it.

Comment: @Svek well actually I tried using the Release build but turns out it's pretty counter-intuitive, the ratio is now about 15 times slower, seems the average time spent on executing a step for the native access is much faster in release while the time waster on the cached compiled lambda expressions is a bit slower. About about wrapping up with a delegate, it does slow things a bit down, but in terms of ratio it should be consistent with or without going this way.

Comment: Well, to your question it's probably not your benchmark method. In response to your statement of "counter-intuitive".... It's most likely a misunderstanding of what's going on under the hood. Maybe you might want to explain where you got your expectation from and maybe form your question differently?

Comment: @Svek well my understanding of what's going under the hood is that the compiled lambda expression (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/LambdaExpression.cs,b6f33ba738236c8d) are translated into ILOpcodes via the LambdaCompiler (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs,9d936e6b32113c6b) and that the IL generated seems to be not that "expensive" in comparison to what could be hand-written. Now I might miss something about what makes that compilation or its execution a lot slower than native calls.

Comment: @Svek also putting aside the symbols loading due to the debug build I don't really see why the native access should be a lot faster while the lambda is sort of more or less stagnant regardless of the type of build.

Comment: Again, to attract the right attention... I would suggest changing your question. There is talent out there that can explain it to you.

Comment: @Svek well actually I managed to find the bottleneck... the dictionary access is far more time-consuming than what I was expecting.

Comment: I see it now. Maybe you can cache the return at the ObjectExtensions to optimize it further? If you have it return a static variable the results look more like what you want. Maybe throw it over to us at Code Review :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in exchange of comments below my question, the problem resides in the way the benchmark is achieved. Actually the bottom line performance-wise is all about the helpers and extensions methods, especially the dictionary lookup operation.

I clearly underestimated the time required by the dictionary (even though it's constant O(1)) for the lookup operation when compared to the execution of the result of the compiled lambda itself, that is it's still a lo0o0ot more slower (and yeah that was the reason why I was originally so much after the performances of the compiled lambdas performances).

As mentioned in the question comments, yes I can cache the result and in that case I get performances that are getting real close to the native property access. The extension method is really handy however it did hide a detail that was really important and hence the reason why I said that the way of bench-marking was not really okay.

Here is below the full code that shed the light of some of the issues about my question:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var stepCount = 5000000UL;

        var dummy = new Dummy();

        const string propertyName = "Soother";

        const bool propertyValue = true;

        var propertyInfo = typeof(Dummy).GetProperty(propertyName);

        var lambdaExpression = FastPropertyFactory.GeneratePropertySetter<Dummy, bool>(propertyName);

        var nativeBenchmark = Benchmark.Run("Native", stepCount, () => dummy.Soother = propertyValue);
        var lambdaExpressionBenchmark = Benchmark.Run("Lambda Expression", stepCount, () => lambdaExpression(dummy, propertyValue));
        var dictionaryLambdaExpressionBenchmark = Benchmark.Run("Dictionary Access + Lambda Expression", stepCount, () => dummy.Set(propertyName, propertyValue));
        var propertyInfoBenchmark = Benchmark.Run("Property Info", stepCount, () => propertyInfo.SetValue(dummy, propertyValue, null));

        var benchmarkReports = new[]
        {
            nativeBenchmark,
            lambdaExpressionBenchmark,
            dictionaryLambdaExpressionBenchmark,
            propertyInfoBenchmark
        }.OrderBy(item => item.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        benchmarkReports.Join(Environment.NewLine).WriteLineToConsole();

        var fastest = benchmarkReports.First().ElapsedMilliseconds;

        benchmarkReports.Select(report => (report.ElapsedMilliseconds / fastest).ToString("0.000")).Join(" < ").WriteLineToConsole();

        var dictionaryAccess = (dictionaryLambdaExpressionBenchmark.ElapsedMilliseconds / lambdaExpressionBenchmark.ElapsedMilliseconds * 100);
        ("Dictionary Access: " + dictionaryAccess + " %").WriteLineToConsole();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Dummy
{
    public Dummy(bool soother = true)
    {
        Soother = soother;
    }

    public bool? Soother { get; set; }
}

public class BenchMarkReport
{
    #region Fields & Properties

    public string Name { get; }

    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime { get; }

    public double ElapsedMilliseconds => ElapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds;

    public ulong StepCount { get; }

    public double StepElapsedMilliseconds => ElapsedMilliseconds / StepCount;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    internal BenchMarkReport(string name, TimeSpan elapsedTime, ulong stepCount)
    {
        Name = name;
        ElapsedTime = elapsedTime;
        StepCount = stepCount;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}: Elapsed = {ElapsedTime} ({ElapsedMilliseconds} ms); Step = {StepElapsedMilliseconds:0.###E+000} ms";
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Benchmark
{
    #region Fields & Properties

    private readonly Action _stepAction;

    public string Name { get; }

    public ulong StepCount { get; }

    public Benchmark(string name, ulong stepCount, Action stepAction)
    {
        Name = name;
        StepCount = stepCount;
        _stepAction = stepAction;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public static BenchMarkReport Run(string name, ulong stepCount, Action stepAction)
    {
        var benchmark = new Benchmark(name, stepCount, stepAction);

        var benchmarkReport = benchmark.Run();

        return benchmarkReport;
    }

    public BenchMarkReport Run()
    {
        return Run(StepCount);
    }

    public BenchMarkReport Run(ulong stepCountOverride)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (ulong i = 0; i < StepCount; i++)
        {
            _stepAction();
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        var benchmarkReport = new BenchMarkReport(Name, stopwatch.Elapsed, stepCountOverride);

        return benchmarkReport;
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void WriteToConsole<TInstance>(this TInstance instance)
    {
        Console.Write(instance);
    }

    public static void WriteLineToConsole<TInstance>(this TInstance instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(instance);
    }

    // Goodies: add name inference from property lambda expression
    // e.g. "instance => instance.PropertyName" redirected using "PropertyName"

    public static TProperty Get<TInstance, TProperty>(this TInstance instance, string propertyName)
    {
        return FastPropertyRepository<TInstance, TProperty>.GetGetter(propertyName)(instance);
    }

    public static void Set<TInstance, TProperty>(this TInstance instance, string propertyName, TProperty propertyValue)
    {
        FastPropertyRepository<TInstance, TProperty>.GetSetter(propertyName)(instance, propertyValue);
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static string Join<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, string separator = ", ")
    {
        return string.Join(separator, source);
    }
}

internal static class FastPropertyRepository<TInstance, TProperty>
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, Action<TInstance, TProperty>> Setters;
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, Func<TInstance, TProperty>> Getters;

    static FastPropertyRepository()
    {
        Getters = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Func<TInstance, TProperty>>();
        Setters = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Action<TInstance, TProperty>>();
    }

    public static Func<TInstance, TProperty> GetGetter(string propertyName)
    {
        if (!Getters.TryGetValue(propertyName, out Func<TInstance, TProperty> getter))
        {
            getter = FastPropertyFactory.GeneratePropertyGetter<TInstance, TProperty>(propertyName);
            Getters[propertyName] = getter;
        }

        return getter;
    }

    public static Action<TInstance, TProperty> GetSetter(string propertyName)
    {
        if (!Setters.TryGetValue(propertyName, out Action<TInstance, TProperty> setter))
        {
            setter = FastPropertyFactory.GeneratePropertySetter<TInstance, TProperty>(propertyName);
            Setters[propertyName] = setter;
        }

        return setter;
    }
}

internal static class FastPropertyFactory
{
    public static Func<TInstance, TProperty> GeneratePropertyGetter<TInstance, TProperty>(string propertyName)
    {
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInstance), "value");

        var propertyValueExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyName);

        var expression = propertyValueExpression.Type == typeof(TProperty) ? propertyValueExpression : (Expression)Expression.Convert(propertyValueExpression, typeof(TProperty));

        var propertyGetter = Expression.Lambda<Func<TInstance, TProperty>>(expression, parameterExpression).Compile();

        return propertyGetter;
    }

    public static Action<TInstance, TProperty> GeneratePropertySetter<TInstance, TProperty>(string propertyName)
    {
        var instanceParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInstance));

        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProperty), propertyName);

        var propertyValueExpression = Expression.Property(instanceParameterExpression, propertyName);

        var conversionExpression = propertyValueExpression.Type == typeof(TProperty) ? parameterExpression : (Expression)Expression.Convert(parameterExpression, propertyValueExpression.Type);

        var propertySetter = Expression.Lambda<Action<TInstance, TProperty>>(Expression.Assign(propertyValueExpression, conversionExpression), instanceParameterExpression, parameterExpression).Compile();

        return propertySetter;
    }
}
```

And for the sake of example here is below the results on my machine:

```
Native: Elapsed = 00:00:00.1346658 (134.6658 ms); Step = 2.693E-005 ms
Lambda Expression: Elapsed = 00:00:00.1578168 (157.8168 ms); Step = 3.156E-005 ms
Dictionary Access + Lambda Expression: Elapsed = 00:00:00.8092977 (809.2977 ms); Step = 1.619E-004 ms
Property Info: Elapsed = 00:00:02.2420732 (2242.0732 ms); Step = 4.484E-004 ms
1.000 < 1.172 < 6.010 < 16.649
Dictionary Access: 512.80833219277 %
```

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your work into smaller methods. It increased the performance overall, but it also widened the gap.

> ```
> Native              : 00:00:00.0029713 (    2.9713ms) 5.9426E-07
> Lambda Expression   : 00:00:00.4356385 (  435.6385ms) 8.71277E-05
> Property Info       : 00:00:01.3436626 ( 1343.6626ms) 0.00026873252
> ```

Here are the methods used

```
public class Dummy
{
    public bool? Soother { get; set; } = true;
}

public class Lab
{
    Dummy _dummy = new Dummy();
    ulong _iterations = 5000000UL;
    const bool _propertyValue = true;
    const string _propertyName = "Soother";

    public BenchmarkReport RunNative()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (ulong i = 0; i < _iterations; i++)
        {
            _dummy.Soother = _propertyValue;
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        return new BenchmarkReport("Native", stopwatch.Elapsed, _iterations);
    }

    public BenchmarkReport RunLambdaExpression()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (ulong i = 0; i < _iterations; i++)
        {
            _dummy.Set(_propertyName, _propertyValue);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        return new BenchmarkReport("Lambda Expression", stopwatch.Elapsed, _iterations);
    }

    public BenchmarkReport RunPropertyInfo()
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Dummy).GetProperty(_propertyName);

        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (ulong i = 0; i < _iterations; i++)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(_dummy, _propertyValue);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        return new BenchmarkReport("Property Info", stopwatch.Elapsed, _iterations);
    }
}

public class BenchmarkReport
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime { get; set; }
    public ulong Iterations { get; set; }

    public BenchmarkReport(string name, TimeSpan elapsedTime, ulong iterations)
    {
        Name = name;
        ElapsedTime = elapsedTime;
        Iterations = iterations;
    }
}
```

and the program to run it

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {

        Lab lab = new Lab();
        List<BenchmarkReport> benchmarkReports = new List<BenchmarkReport>()
        {
            lab.RunNative(),
            lab.RunLambdaExpression(),
            lab.RunPropertyInfo()
        };

        foreach (var report in benchmarkReports)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} ({2}ms) {3}",
                report.Name.PadRight(20),
                report.ElapsedTime,
                report.ElapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds.ToString().PadLeft(10),
                (double)report.ElapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds / report.Iterations);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```